# How to print out only one category by records, and other records under there in table?

Tags: php, mysql, printing, html-table

I have quite a strange problem during development, it is simple to explain. I have a table of Sortiments, and each belongs to any Category. Let's see:

```
Sortiment 1 | Category 2
Sortiment 2 | Category 3 
Sortiment 3 | Category 1 
Sortiment 4 | Category 1 
Sortiment 5 | Category 1 
Sortiment 6 | Category 3
```

Now, that I want to order by category gets easy:

```
SELECT * FROM sortiment ORDER BY category

Sortiment 3 | Category 1 
Sortiment 4 | Category 1 
Sortiment 5 | Category 1 
Sortiment 1 | Category 2
Sortiment 2 | Category 3 
Sortiment 6 | Category 3
```

If we do this one:

```
<table>
<?php
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
     echo "<tr> <td>" . $r['sortiment'] . "</td> </tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

I get the following scheme (without category):

```
<table> 
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 3 </td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 4 </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 5 </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 1 </td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 2 </td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 6 </td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
```

But that's not what I need. I need a following print out:

```
<table> 
   <tr class="mycategory"> 
      <td> Category 1 </td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 3 </td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 4 </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 5 </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr class="mycategory"> 
      <td> Category 2 </td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 1 </td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr class="mycategory"> 
      <td> Category 3 </td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 2 </td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
      <td> Sortiment 6 </td> 
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Note, that not care about the order of categories and sortiments.

```
<table>
<?php
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
   if (header) {
     ... once write header of category ...
   } else {
     echo "<tr> <td>" . $r['sortiment'] . "</td> </tr>";
   }
}
?>
</table>
```

How to print out a **`<tr class="mycategory">Specific category</tr>`** once like above scheme?

Comment: I need print out like scheme above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

use a temp variable to compare category title;

```
<?php 
$sortiments = mysql_fetch_array($q,MYSQL_ASSOC);
$tmp_category_header = null;
foreach($sortiments as $sortiment):
   $category  = $sortiment['category_title']; // category name
   $sortiment_label = $sortiment['sortiment_label']; // sortiment
?>   

   <?php if($tmp_category_header == null || $tmp_category_header != $category): ?>
      <tr>
        <th><?php echo $category; ?></th>
     </tr>
   <?php endif; ?>

   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $sortiment_label; ?></td>
   <tr>

   <?php $tmp_category_header = $category; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Consider changing you `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` - mysql_* is deprecated.